Style not being applied when using the host property of the component decorator
I'm trying to apply a class to a component using the host property of the component decorator, but it's not working.
Here's the HTML:
<div class="container">
 <app-header></app-header>
 <div class="content">
    <router-outlet/>
 </div>
</div>

Here's the component
@Component({
  //...
  host: {
    'class': 'header-bg'
  },
  //...
 })
 export class HeaderComponent {}

And here's the style:
.header-bg {
  background-color: aqua;
}


It's not clear where this style lives.
I'm assuming it's in the container component, since it's not working.
Angular encapsulates styles so they only apply to the component whose CSS file they live in.
::ng-deep is the naive approach, making global styles from a component-level CSS file.
I would suggest adding the header-bg style in your app-header component instead. That should work.
If you want to make the bg-color configurable, you could create an input on app-header like "headerColor" or "headerType" and add a class to the header based on that.
Header TS:
@Input() headerColor: string;
Header HTML:
<div class="header color-{{headerColor}}>
Header CSS:
.color-blue { background-color: blue }
Container HTML:
<app-header color="blue">

the header-bg class was in the styles.scss. I just moved it to header.component.scss, but it's still not working.

Now, I know why it wasn't working. the component has a p tag with the text header works! , which is taking the entire real estate. I just removed the p tag and left the text, applied display block and border, it's like a div now an aqua background-color.

I put the style back to styles.scss file and it's still working. Thank you

Awesome, glad to hear. If a style is specific to this component, it's better to leave it in the component. This creates a modular style structure. Only make global what needs to be global (styles.scss).
